# Подключение к Postgresql из хранимой функции С++ Qt

Tags: postgresql

Добрый день!
Пишу хранимую функцию, для Postgre в виде библиотеки C++ Qt.
Среди прочего эта библиотека должна будет уметь делать запросы к БД из которой она была вызвана.
Если вписать логин, пароль и бд в коде, типа такого:

```
   QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QPSQL");
   db.setDatabaseName("test");
   db.setUserName("postgres");
   db.setPassword("123456");
```

То всё прекрасно подключается и работает. Но проблема в том, что я не могу знать заранее, из какой БД и от какого пользователя эта библиотека была вызвана. 
Можно ли как-то это обойти? 
Спасибо!

Comment: не доходит, если это функция то почему не передавать ей параметры?

Comment: @maint Вот в том то и фокус, из самой БД тоже нет возможности получить пароль пользователя от которого идёт подключение. Ну по крайней мере я такого не нашел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё оказалось гораздо проще!
Как выяснилось, для обращения к БД из библиотеки вообще не требуется знать ничего ни о БД, ни и пользователе.
Достаточно подключить к проекту `executor/spi.h` и вуаля, мы можем спокойно работать с БД из контекста которой была вызвана библиотека.

http://postgresql.ru.net/manual/spi-examples.html